# How does Excel Solver compare 2 [n*n]matrices in a constraint

Tags: solver

Suppose i have 2 tables t1, t2 (or matrices) that are both square (e.g. both are 3X3).

In Solver I add the following constraint :

t1 >= t2

Then how does solver compare these values? 
-Value at 1X1 in t1 >= 1X1 in t2, 1X2 in t1 >= 1X2 in t2,... 
-Any value in t1 must be >= the largest value in t2
-...

If it is not the one, how can I obtain the first situation? Do I enter every value comparison by hand (since that will take quite some time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes the comparison element-wise. You can confirm by getting the "Answer Report".

[image]

Here are the matrices on `C5:G19` and `J5:N19`

[image]

You add the constraint stating `C5:G9` <= (or >=) `J5:N9`

[image]

As you can see from the formula column, it makes the comparisons element-wise (`C5<J5`, `D5<K5`, ..., `G9<N9`).